# Make pdf file accessible through a link in the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, file, pdf

I've been searching for weeks on stackoverflow and google, but I wasn't able to find any good results.

I have a pdf file on my computer and I want to access that pdf file from an ios app, by clicking a link which will take me to that pdf file.

And when I modify that pdf file on my computer I want the link in the app to update with the latest version of that pdf file.

I thought of using a backend for storage such as Firebase storage but I had some issues with that.

How can I access that pdf file from an app? It doesn't have to be through a link, anything that will allow access with the latest version of the file is fine.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way may be using a cloud storage such as Dropbox, Google Drive, One Drive...etc and get the public share link to that file. Then you can load the PDF in your iOS app using this link.

Comment: i thought of that as well but when I modify the pdf file and I upload it again to say for example google drive, will I not get a new link for that file? And if that happens how can I update the xcode project with the new link? Thanks

Comment: The link you generate from those cloud storages always point to the latest version of that file. So you always get the latest version of that file using that unique link. Unless you want to actively change your sharing link each time you update the file, then you can think about using service like Push Notification or Firebase RemoteConfig.

Comment: thank you @qtngo. I know I need a developer account for push notifications, but do I need an apple developer account to use Firebase RemoteConfig? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about all the constraints of not having an Apple developer account, but the first problem is that you can't load the app on your real device. Otherwise I don't think you will have problem in developing your app with Firebase RemoteConfig.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using web services API, You need to create simple webservice in backend (in any language for example PHP) to get the list of file with path to access in mobile app, and configure backend webservice code to your server (your computer, wherever you want to update files), So you can get every time updated data (files path) using webservice.